# Public include directory not added in referenced project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have added a path in VS2022 to a C++ project under `project property page` => `public include directories`. Let's call it `Project A`

`Project A` was added with `add Reference` as reference to C++ `Project B`. However, `Project B` does not recognize the include paths of `Project A`.

Do I need to set something else?

Answer (score 0):

requires at least Platform Toolset v143

Previously, an older version was used.